# Order by Empty String Last on Concatenated Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I am trying to order a table alphabetically, ascending, with nulls last but am having problems.

The code below produces the following error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

```
select distinct 
'item' = othertab..item,
'stockedFor' = tab..stocked_for
          + ', ' + tab..stockedFor2
          + ', '+ tab..stockedFor3

from tab

order by case when stockedFor is null then 1 else 0 end, stockedFor
```

How can I return `stockedFor` alphabetically and nulls last?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in another select statement:

```
select stockedFor
from (
       select distinct 
       'stockedFor' = tab..stocked_for
                 + ', ' + tab..stockedFor2
                 + ', '+ tab..stockedFor3
       from tab
     ) x
order by case when stockedFor is null then 1 else 0 end, stockedFor
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are removing duplicates, a workaround is to use `GROUP BY` to remove duplicates instead of `DISTINCT`.  The question has changed but the method still applies if putting all columns in the `SELECT` in the `GROUP BY`.

For example:

```
select 
'item' = othertab..item,
'stockedFor' = tab..stocked_for
          + ', ' + tab..stockedFor2
          + ', '+ tab..stockedFor3

from tab
GROUP BY othertab..item,
         tab..stocked_for
          + ', ' + tab..stockedFor2
          + ', '+ tab..stockedFor3

order by case when stockedFor is null then 1 else 0 end, stockedFor
```

Comment: Not sure if this method still works when you add another variable to the select statement. I had omitted it in the first version of this question.  I get the following error with this method, `Column 'othertab..item' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Taking distinct values using `GROUP BY` would work if _every column_ in the `SELECT` is included in the `GROUP BY`.  In this error mentioned, the `othertab...item` column was not included in the `GROUP BY`.  The error hints at the problem: 'othertab..item is invalid in the select list because ...  it is not contained in ... the GROUP BY clause."